# How can you use a method from a parent controller to set a private variable in php?

Tags: php, class-variables, variable-declaration

I have a simple MVC framework I'm using where I use the following call to load a model in each function in the controller:

```
$member_model = $this->loadModel('Members');
```

What I would like to do is call that once so every function in the Member Controller can use it rather than calling it in every function.

Something like:

```
class Members extends Controller
{
    private $member_model = $this->loadModel('Members');

    function myFunction(){
        myvar = $member_model->someFunction();
    }
}
```

**Note:** loadModel is a method of the Controller class of which the Members controller extends.

I get a range of different errors depending on whether the variable is private/public or neither however it works within a function.

Is it even possible to do this at the class level, if so how?

**Update 1**

Members Controller

```
class Members extends Controller
{

private $member_model = null;


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->member_model = $this->loadModel('Members');

}
}
```

Controller Class

```
class Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    Session::init();

    try {
        $this->db = new Database();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Database connection could not be established.');
    }

    $this->view = new View();
}

public function loadModel($name)
{
    $path = MODELS_PATH . strtolower($name) . '_model.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require MODELS_PATH . strtolower($name) . '_model.php';
        $modelName = $name . 'Model';
        return new $modelName($this->db);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in a constructor

```
class Members extends Controller
{
  private $member_model = null;

  public function __constructor() {
       parent::_constructor(); 
       $this->member_model = $this->loadModel('Members');
    }
   function myFunction(){
    $myvar = $member_model->someFunction();
   }
}
```

Comment: If I include it in my constructor I get a db error if its before the `parent::__construct();` and I get a "Cannot redeclare class ClassesModel" if it comes after it.  See edits for code.

Comment: then call the parent constructer first ... without more details it's not possible to help you ... i changed the code with parent constructer first

Comment: I included the code in my edits. does anything stand out there?

Comment: change also require MODELS_PATH to **require_once** MODELS_PATH

Comment: Getting **undefined variable: member_model** error now.  Nvm I'll just call it in each function.

Comment: sorry .... check your code .. i don't see any propperty / variable called **error** in your code.